# How to batch move folders up one sub-directory on Mac?

Tags: macos, batch-processing, archive

I have a large music library (>20000 songs) that I am trying to move from my Mac to my PC. The individual files that comprise this library were collected on my Mac over a long period of time. All were extracted from compressed archives, e.g. .zip or .rar. Unfortunately, the unpacker program I used to extract these files placed them all into a newly created folder before extraction. Because these archives were all just zipped folders, I now have a bunch of files that are inside nested redundant directories.

For example, let's say I extracted an archive named ABCDWXYZ.zip.

This archive itself was simply a compressed version of the folder ABCDWXYZ, inside which were the files Track 1, Track 2, etc. However, the extraction program that I used first created a new folder named ABCDWXYZ and then proceeded to extract the contents of the archive into this folder, resulting in several thousand pathnames that all look like this:

```
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/ABCDWXYZ/Track 1.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/ABCDWXYZ/Track 2.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/ABCDWXYZ/Track 3.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/ABCDWXYZ/Track 4.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/ABCDWXYZ/Track 5.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/QWERTY/Track 1.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/QWERTY/Track 2.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/QWERTY/Track 3.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/QWERTY/Track 4.mp3
```

is there some way to batch move all of these doubly nested folders up one directory? after executing the batch move, i would like the resulting file architecture to look something like this:

```
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/Track 1.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/Track 2.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/Track 3.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/Track 4.mp3
iTunes/ABCDWXYZ/Track 5.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/Track 1.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/Track 2.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/Track 3.mp3
iTunes/QWERTY/Track 4.mp3
```

some more information about the files that may help you in answering my question:

- all files are inside one folder (namely, iTunes).
- the names of the redundant folders are not identical in every case (this is because i would sometimes shorten the name of the archive before unzipping, resulting in something like /iTunes/YUI/YUIOP/Track 1.mp3), but in the majority of cases they are identical. hopefully this doesn't affect solution of the problem.
- i am terribly illiterate at the command line and would very much appreciate it if any proposed solutions could be a little bit more "patronizing" than usual. explain like i am 5, if possible.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could open Finder and search for all .mp3 files and then drop them into the iTunes window to have them reprocessed. It might leave a few empty folders but as long as you're not OCD for that, you'll have your music back.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script (from within the `iTunes` directory):

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
for d in *
do
    if [ -d "$d" -a -d "$d"/"$d" ]; then
        echo Processing $d
        mv "$d"/"$d" "$d.tmp" || exit 2
        rm -rf "$d" || exit 3
        mv "$d.tmp" "$d" || exit 4
    fi
done
```

NOTE:

1. This is untested. **Use at your own risk!**.
2. Test it by copying some directories elsewhere and trying it on them before running it on your music collection.

Comment: how would i go about "using this script from within the iTunes directory"? sorry for the dumb question, but i really don't know. do i just open up terminal and throw all this in there, specifying the directory where the * is? please help me understand a little more.

Comment: You need to type that into a file using a text editor, save it into a directory and then open terminal.app and `cd /path/to/itunes`. Then do `sh scripname.sh`.  This stuff is worth learning about as its a powerful feature of Unix that the Mac inherits.